# Maximum length of a table name in Accumulo

Tags: java, apache-zookeeper, key-value-store, accumulo, nosql

I've a use case where-in I have to create accumulo tables dynamically on user inputs. One of the concerns that I have is where there exists any maximum length for table name in accumulo? If yes, then what is it?

Comment: Internally Accumulo generates its own ID for a table, the name is just a piece of metadata associated with that ID. I'm not sure if there's a maximum, i would suggest you just try creating a table with a large name and see what happens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of the latest version at the time of this writing (1.8.1), there is no hard-coded limit imposed on the length of the table name. This could (and probably will, eventually) change in future versions.

Excessively large table names could hypothetically cause performance problems with internal data structures, or out of memory errors.

I'd recommend keeping them a reasonable length, since these names are intended to be human-readable. Anything larger than 50 characters seems excessive to me, personally, but an order of magnitude above that would probably not cause noticeable issues.